# Eloquent Many to Many with Pivot table to refactor the returned results to a specific array

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.4

I have a pivot table that stores data to synchronise three other tables

[image: Table]

I have a function that will return the rows that based on a specific field.such as device_id

```
public function getDeviceReleasesByProfileId($profile_id)
{
    try {
        $profile = Profile::find($profile_id);
        if (!$profile) {
            return $this->respondNotFound('Profile not found');
        }
        $profile_releases = DeviceProfileRelease::where('profile_id', '=', $profile_id)->get();

        // Refactor to array here. 

        return $this->respondWithSuccess($profile_releases);
    } catch (\Exception $error) {
        return $this->respondInternalError($error->getMessage());
    }
}
```

What I need to do is get these results which currently come back as 

`[
  {
    "device_id": 19,
    "profile_id": 7,
    "release_id": 1
  },
  {
    "device_id": 19,
    "profile_id": 7,
    "release_id": 2
  },
  {
    "device_id": 19,
    "profile_id": 7,
    "release_id": 3
  },
  {
    "device_id": 19,
    "profile_id": 7,
    "release_id": 4
  }
]`

What I am hoping to achieve is to for each of these results, use the 
`$profile_releases->release()->get()` method to change the results to a list of releases instead of an array of pivoted values. My question is, have I architected the pivot table in the wrong way and is there a way to refactor this for optimal performance and better code.

I know it can be done like this,

```
        $releases = array();
        foreach ($profile_releases as $profile_release)
        {
            $release_search = Release::find($profile_release->release_id);
            $releases[] = $release_search;
        }
```

I just want to see if anybody has any other ideas as to a better approach, this feels wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public function getDeviceReleasesByProfileId($profile_id)
{
    try {
        $profile = Profile::find($profile_id);
        if (!$profile) {
            return $this->respondNotFound('Profile not found');
        }
        $profile_releases = DeviceProfileRelease::where('profile_id', '=', $profile_id)->get();
        $release_ids = array();
        foreach ($profile_releases as $profile_release)
        {
            $release_ids[] = $profile_release->release_id;
        }
        $repository = app('App\Interfaces\ReleaseRepository');
        $repository->setPresenter(ReleasePresenter::class);
        $releases = $repository->find($release_ids);

        return $this->respondWithSuccess($releases);
    } catch (\Exception $error) {
        return $this->respondInternalError($error->getMessage());
    }
}
```